# how we can prove that argument $P_1,P_2,...,P_n $?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

I ran into a one claims on LOGIC. how can add more direction or hint to me?

> if we have an argument $P_1,P_2,...,P_n  $ such that $  n>3$ ($p_i$ is
>   premise) why $P_1,P_2,....,P_n,P_1$ is necessarily be an argument?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understood your question correctly:

Let $p,q$ be two propositions, then according to the simplification rule the proposition $(p\wedge q) \to p$ is a tautology. Therefore, $(p\wedge q) \Rightarrow p$ is a valid argument.

You can prove this rule using truth-tables, and then extend it to any finite number of propositions $p_i$ (induction).

Comment: so why $P_3,P_2,P_1,P_4,...,P_n$ not necessarily an argument ?

Comment: What are the premises and what is the conclusion?

Comment: $P_n$ is conclusion and all remain is premise.

Comment: So you have premises $P_1,...,P_{n-1}$ and a conclusion $P_n$? Then $P_n$ does not necessary follow from the premises. I mean, what do you know about $P_n$?